# TIMED OUT error with PhoneGap Android Developer App

Tags: android, cordova

everyone.
Yesterday I created a simple PhoneGap app which I tested with new [PhoneGap Desktop App](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/11/phonegap-desktop-app-beta/) on Mac and 
[PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com) on Android.

Everything was fine, but today I can't connect to server on my Android PhoneGap Developer App – there is an error "TIMED OUT!" on the screen.

Both devices are inside the same wi-fi network. Could you have any ideas what can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found! It was a bug with a new PhoneGap Desktop App.

Mac IP changes after each internet reconnection but server IP doesn't change in App.

You need to reload all system or try to find your new IP – you will need this IP to type it inside Android/iOS Developer App.

Hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: yup, confusing for beginners